# Usb 3.0 not working

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I have a  Lenovo g580 laptop and installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS alongside Windows 7 on it. For a week or so everything worked fine, until one of the USB 3.0 ports stopped working. Soon after that, the other port stopped working too. The one USB 2 port still works fine. When I connect my phone to a USB 3 port it charges, but Ubuntu doesn't recognize that a device is connected. My wireless mouse doesn't work either on those ports.

I've googled around but nothing seems to help. I've updated my bios and added a "pci=nomsi" line to grub file. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Do the ports work in Windows?

Comment: @Melebius I do have the same problem with kernel 5.3, while the USB 3 port **didn't** work in Windows 7. But booting an older kernel (4.15), it started working.